# bounding $\|A^K x\|_2$ more tightly than $\|A\|^k_{op} \|x\|$ when $\rho(A) < 1$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, dynamical-systems, singular-values, matrix-norms

Let $\|\cdot\|$ denote the Euclidean operator norm when applied to matrices, and the $L2$ norm when applied to vectors.
Let $\rho(\cdot)$ denote the spectral radius (maximum magnitude of $A$'s eigenvalues).
$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}$

---

Given $A \in \R^{n \times n}$ and $x \in \R^n$, by definition
$
\| A x \| \leq \|A\| \|x\|,
$
and therefore
$$
\| A^k x \| \leq \|A\|^k \|x\|.
$$
On the other hand, if $\rho(A) < 1$, then
$$
\lim_{k \to \infty} \|A^k\| = 0.
$$
So in the case where $\rho(A) < 1,\ \|A\| > 1$, the $\|A\|^k$ bound is loose to the point of being useless.

---

The difficulty in bounding $\|A^k x\|$ is that in the sequence
$
x_1 = Ax,\ x_2 = A^2 x,\ \dots ,
$
it's possible that $\|A x\| > \|x\|,\ \|A^2 x\| > \|x\|$, and so on.
The sequence of $\|x_n\|$ might look something like this:
[image]

The *Kreiss matrix theorem* states that if $\rho(A) < 1$, there exists a constant $C$ (details omitted) such that 
$$
\sup_k \|A^k\| < C.
$$
However, a constant bound like this does not help my application.

---

**Question**:
When $\rho(A) < 1$ and $\|A\|>1$, does there exist a bound $B$ of the form
$$
\|A^k x\| < B(A, k) \|x\|
$$
such that $\lim_{k \to \infty} B(A, k) = 0$?

Comment: [Gelfand's formula for the spectral radius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_radius#Gelfand's_formula)?

Comment: This gives the asymptotic convergence but I am looking for a computable function for specific k. (I think I have already found an answer in a linear systems theory textbook, but need to make sure I didn't miss anything.)

Comment: Could you cite book?

Comment: @tommsch check Theorems 16.1 and 16.2 in:

Lloyd N Trefethen and Mark Embree. Spectra and pseudospectra: The Behavior of Nonnormal Matrices and Operators. Princeton University Press, 2005.